# Excel VLOOKUP referencing a range

Tags: excel-2013

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2013.
I've been given these tables of postcode ranges, and associated zone number, as follows:

[image: Postcode Ranges vs Zone]

and I want to separate the postcodes, so it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried VLOOKUP, but it doesn't quite do what I want... as it looks uses the first column as a reference, and this doesn't seem changable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Vlookup with TRUE as the fourth parameter, so it performs an approximate lookup. But your data has gaps. There are no number below 200, according to your top table. Also, there are no postcodes between 299 and 800, so what should the formula return if you build a list of numbers that starts with 0 and increments by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the gaps in the post codes, you'll need to construct the list of postcodes carefully, to include only those that are actually in a valid range. Then you can use a Vlookup with TRUE as the fourth parameter.

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A:C,3,TRUE)
```

According to your screenshot, there is no postcode with numbers 300 to 799, so you can't have 300 in the list. It will return a zone because Vlookup with the TRUE parameter returns the result for the next smallest match if no exact match is found. In the case of the missing post codes that would be a wrong result, right? So, don't use the numbers that are not valid post codes. Also note that the data must be sorted ascending by the values in the first column.

[image]

**Edit:** If you want to use all numbers from 0 to the end and run a formula, you need to check first if a number exists in a given range. So you could do something like this:

```
=IF(E2<=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)),VLOOKUP(E2,A:C,3,1),"not in range")
```

[image]

You should not start your list with 0, though, but with your smallest post code. Otherwise the formula will need to get even more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... yes... the gaps in the data make it a little difficult, and labour intensive. Was hoping there was a VLOOKUP RANGE sort of thing. Thank you for the info on VLOOKUP, that's how I'll do it for now

Comment: Nup, there must be an easier way! this is taking a long time

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer

Comment: ahh you're awesome. That did the trick! I don't fully understand the formula though! will have to study it for a bit. Much appreciated!